# How many terms in the expansion $(6xy +4x + 3y + 2)^{50}$

Tags: combinatorics

How many terms are in the expansion of $(6xy + 4x + 3y + 2)^{50}$?

**Attempt:**

First, I thought that the answer would be $\dbinom{50+3}{3}$, but that wasn't the right answer. Next, I attempted to factor the expression to

$$(2x+1)^{50}(3y+2)^{50},$$

but then I was stuck from here. I'm wondering why $\dbinom{50+3}{3}$ doesn't work, and are there any clues to help solve this problem?

Comment: How many terms in the expansion $(6xy +4x + 3y + 2)^2?$

Comment: Some of the terms you get from the multiplication can be combined into a single term. E.g., $\cdots4x\cdot3y+\cdots3y\cdot4x+\cdots=\cdots24yx\cdots$.

Answer (score 3):

$(2x+1)^{50}(3y+2)^{50}$ looks like a good place to start.

$(2x+1)^{50}$ will be a $50$ degree polynomial which has $51$ places, because there will be also be a constant term.

$(3y+2)^{50}$ will also be a $50$ degree polynomial.

$(P(x))(Q(y))$ will then the product of two 50 degree polynomials.  Each time we multiply an $x^n$ by a $y^m$ term we create a unique $x^ny^m$ term.

$51^2$ total terms.

Answer (score 2):

Using your factoring, $(2x+1)^{50}$ has $51$ terms, i.e.monimials in $x$ with degree from $0$ to $50$, similarly for $(3y+2)^{50}$.

Multiplying them together, you will get all the monorails of the form $x^ny^m$ with $n,m$ ranging from $0$ to $50$, so you have $51^2$ terms.